# How to always Show Bottom Tabs Label in React Native Navigation V5?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2'}}
        initialRouteName="Catalog">
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings"
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Alterações',
            title: 'Configurações',
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cog" color="#000" size={22} />
            ),
          }}>
          {(props) => (
            <Settings
              {...props}
              params={{
                cpf: params.cpf ? params.cpf : cpf,
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Tab.Screen>

        <Tab.Screen
          name="Catalog"
          options={{
            tabBarVisible: false,
            title: 'Ofertas',
          }}>
          {(props) => (
            <Catalog
              {...props}
              params={{
                pracaId: params.pracaId ? params.pracaId : pracaId,
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Tab.Screen>
           [...]
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
```

The documentations says to use the `titleDisplayMode` but where? when? I only find solution for older versions. I need it to v5.
Please, can some one help me?

I have include some part of my code to understend how I'm using the lib

Comment: Have you checked this docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens. It have an example how you hide or show the bottom tabs on some specific screens.

Comment: but I want to always show de label. By default the tab's label only appears if you're in the correspondent screen

Answer (score 4):

There is a shifting prop that you can put to false in your navigator :

```
 <Tab.Navigator
    barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2'}}
    initialRouteName="Catalog"
    shifting={false} 
  >
   .....
```

Whether the shifting style is used, the active tab icon shifts up to show the label and the inactive tabs won't have a label.

By default, this is true when you have more than 3 tabs. Pass shifting={false} to explicitly disable this animation, or shifting={true} to always use this animation.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/material-bottom-tab-navigator#shifting

Comment: shifting={false} was what I was looking for. Now the labels always show up with their respective icons. Thanks for pointing me back at the manual (RTFM lol)

Answer (score 1):

I have created this example where the `HomeScreen` always hide the bottom tab and the `SettingsStack` always show the bottom tab automatically. The key point is basically these lines of code, one have just a screen and the other one have a StackNavigator:

```
<Tab.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
<Tab.Screen name="SettingsStack" component={SettingsStack} />
```

[image: hiding/showing bottom tab]

This example is similar to the one in the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/, but with more components.

The code below is in snack, check if this helps you:
https://snack.expo.io/@ronicesarrc/react-navigation-hiding-showing-bottom-tab-navigator

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

function SettingsInternalScreen() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
      }}>
      <Text>SettingsInternalScreen!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', padding: 16 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SettingsInternalScreen')}>
        <Text>Go to Screen showing bottom tab</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const SettingStack = createStackNavigator();

function SettingsStack() {
  return (
    <SettingStack.Navigator>
      <SettingStack.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <SettingStack.Screen
        name="SettingsInternalScreen"
        component={SettingsInternalScreen}
      />
    </SettingStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray', padding: 16 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeInternalScreen')}>
        <Text>Go to Screen hidding bottom tab</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeInternalScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>HomeInternalScreen!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SettingsStack" component={SettingsStack} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MainStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <MainStack.Screen name={'Tabs'} component={Tabs} />
        <MainStack.Screen
          name={"HomeInternalScreen"}
          component={HomeInternalScreen}
        />
      </MainStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```